# Pull page content from master site in WordPress

Tags: seo, wordpress, rss

So I am working on some sites for a health practice, all in Wordpress. I have one parent hub site that contains all the information about all the treatments they offer on different pages. I also have many different sites for different clinics and doctors which share the same treatments. I would like to be able to pull the treatment data from my parent site and have it visible in each clinic site.

I have accomplished a basic version of this via RSS feeds which would work great but I don't know if this will work because I have been reading that Google doesn't index RSS feeds, which would be a problem for marketing each clinic individually. And then there is the problem of having duplicate content on each site. What will this do to the SEO? All the sites will be on the same domain.

Any ideas? I'm looking for a solution because our writers don't want to have to rewrite all the content for each client, but I also don't want to ruin our PPC advertisting and page rankings.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend re-using content from the parent site to each clinic website for the same treatment. Google will consider this as duplicate content and may penalize any or all websites engaging in the practice.

Instead try one or all of these solutions:

- Try to make unique content for each clinic for these pages - home
  page, contact page, about us page, unique services offered by this
  clinic.
- If you absolutely must duplicate the content, I would recommend you use the canonical tag that
  points to original URL.
- You may also want to investigate using curated content.

All the best.

Answer (score 1):

> All the sites will be on the same domain.

Do you mean subdomain for every clinic site?

It will not be the problem. You may target every subdomain site for the territory and audience you need. The only requirement will be to put the link to the parent URL in the end of each article.

Also you may to submit your authorship by integration with your Google+ account to show Google the source of the content.